# If I virtualise my work laptop can I use both the virtualised and physical instances

Tags: laptop, virtual-machine, vmware, active-directory, computing-environment

I'm quite keen to virtualise my work laptop so that I can leave my work device in my bag when I get home and fire up my much nicer and more powerful home PC to continue my work. I know this isn't a problem to virtualise the device however I would be still keen to continue to use the work laptop during the day (in the office or at client site) when away from home.

All of my needed files and documents are stored in a private cloud so there is no issue on accessing them there but worried about effectively cloning the device and how services such as Active Directory will work with this?

Comment: Why do you want to virtualize anything? All your data is in the cloud, so why don't you work on that at any computer. Where is your problem?

Comment: The only problem you might run into is a legality issue since a Windows license cannot be used for both physical and virtual hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Virtualize the hard drive and put that on a share.  Then, point instances of the VM to the hard drive from any device running the emulator, and voila, exactly what you want!

P.S. I've done this with great success using Virtual Box.